# Me sale un error con pynput

Tags: python

alguien sabes como lo puedo mejorar. a mi me sale un error y no funciona. lo que yo quiero crear aqui es que abra el bloc de nota y escriba el link y cuando yo precione la letra 'e' se pare todo. pero me sale un error es lo siguiente

"Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function SystemHook._handler at 0x000002B024EA8160>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pynput_util\win32.py", line 165, in _handler
return SystemHook._CallNextHookEx(0, code, msg, lpdata)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert"

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from time import sleep
import pyautogui

#Variable global para detectar si se ha presionado la tecla "e"
e_press = False

#Función para detectar teclas presionadas
def on_press(key):
  #Uso de la variable global
  global e_press
  #No todas las teclas tienen .char (Por ejemplo shift), por eso hay que usar try - 
except
try:
    if key.char == 'e':
        e_press = True
        print('La tecla "e" ha sido presionada')
        #Detener el listener
        return False
except:
    pass

#Inicialización del contador
i = 1

def accion():
   pyautogui.press('win')
   sleep(1)

   pyautogui.typewrite("note")
   sleep(1)
   pyautogui.press('enter')
   sleep(1)
   pyautogui.typewrite('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJJEEv_csQk')
   pyautogui.press('enter')

   sleep(5)


   for i in range(10):
       pyautogui.press('up')
    


  #Listener
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
   #Se ejecuta mientras no se haya presionado la tecla "e"
   while not e_press:
      print(i)
      i = i+1
      accion()
      sleep(1)
   listener.join()
```

si alguien sabe me puede ayudar escribiéndolo en los comentarios. gracias

Comment: Buen día, tienes preguntas que han recibido respuesta y no has aceptado, por favor lee la sección [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y procesa las preguntas que has hecho, si tienen respuestas válidas entonces acéptalas, si tienen respuestas que no solucionan tu problema entonces agrega un comentario explicando lo que hace falta.

Comment: Varias cosas: no sé si fue un error al copiar pero tú código tiene el primer try fuera de la función  on_press, que dicho sea de paso te devolverá false al usar la "e" para escribir note, me es díficil saber donde puede estar el error sin reproducirlo, pero ¿por qué no ejecutas por partes así es más simple ver que función da el error?